# I want to know how I get only document Id from firestore database in flutter application

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a flutter project. I want that when user enter name,email,password I have to check that whether the email present in my firestore database or not. If present it tells user to change the email if it exist.
In my firestore database collection name is users, document name is email(which is unique for every user), and there is only one feild inside which is name

I had wrote the code to get the document ID but every time it show document does exist. I don't know what's the mistake i am doing. Here is the code:

```
Future<String?> getDocumentID(String documentID) async {
try{
  DocumentReference docReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(documentID);
  //final docReference = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  print('beforePrint');
  print(docReference);
  print('After Print');
  if (docReference.toString().isEmpty) {
    return 'Document does not exist';
  }
  else if (docReference.toString().isNotEmpty) {
    return 'Document does exist';
  }
}catch(e){
  return 'Error Fecthing Data';
}
}
```

I just want to check that the user input email is exist in my database(document) if yes then {...} and if doesn't then {...}

Thank you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        collection('users')
        .doc(documentID)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.exists) {
      return true;
      }else{
      return false;
      }
     }
```